# Separating hand written numbers on a squared paper form its background

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, handwriting

I am new in matlab and I am trying to write a code that can separate hand written numbers  form a squared page background. I have tried using kmeans  to differ the numbers from the lines and the squers , but it doesn’t work on all images  .
Any ideas how can I do it?
Tahnks!

Comment: Could you show an example image + the result of your attempt (including the used code)?

Comment: Sure, here is a link to download the code :
http://www.speedyshare.com/9KAK7/Untitled.m
and a link to a "good" picture : 
http://www.speedyshare.com/X8c8T/1.jpeg
and link to a "bad" picture :
http://www.speedyshare.com/RCSaU/badpic.jpg

Comment: and here is a word document that shows the results :
http://www.speedyshare.com/B3rkx/results.docx

Comment: Interesting project you have here.  While there are many complex computer vision and image processing solutions to this problem, I think your solution so far is pretty good as far as simple implementations go.  I think one technique to look at would be 2D fourier tranforms; the periodic grid lines in the background are a prime target for frequency filters.

Comment: ur links don't work anymore. Could you post workable links again? I'd like to have a loot at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the EBImage package in R, but I'm sure you can find the equivilent in matlab:

Starting with the original image:
[image]

```
# Read and extract greyscale image 
# Run kmeans with 3 centers 
km = kmeans(as.vector(x), 3)
c = km$centers

# 1 0.4936797
# 2 0.2841005
# 3 0.6456494

# Extract smallest cluster 2 (your numbers) as binary image
t = (km$cluster==2)
r = matrix(t, nrow(x))
```

r now looks like:

[image]

```
# Apply morphological opening (erode then dilate) with smallest possible structural element
kern = makeBrush(3, 'box')

#[,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    1    1
#[2,]    1    1    1
#[3,]    1    1    1

z = openingGreyScale(r, kern)
```

z now looks like

[image]